# Kivy: assigning actions/classifying buttons in grid

Tags: python, user-interface, button, kivy, grid-layout

I'm having an issue with assigning actions to the buttons I've put in a grid in kivy. Any help would be appreciated.

I am new to all things coding but I have been trying to work this out. I tried to assign a name to the button but it doesn't work because the 'on_press' function doesn't work for a string, only a button. Is there any way I can classify my string from the grid as a button or am I doing everything wrong? I would like every button to perform a different action so they cannot be classified as the same thing.

Here is my code:

```
    import kivy 
kivy.require('1.10.0') 
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout 
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.core.window import Window 
from kivy.uix.button import Button


    class MyApp(App):

        def build(self):
            def callback(instance):
                print('The button 1 is being pressed' % instance.text)

            # test 1: I dont think this works because it doesn't work with the grid structure but I tried it anyways
    # btn1 = Button(background_color=blue, text='a', size_hint_x=None, width=butw)

    # test 2: I don't think it works because it is not classified as a button, but a string.
    # btn1 = "layout.add_widget(Button(background_color=blue, text='a', size_hint_x=None, width=butw))"

            btn1.bind(on_press=callback)

            layout = GridLayout(cols=1, rows=28, row_force_default=True, row_default_height=buth)
            layout.add_widget(Button(background_color=blue, text='a', size_hint_x=None, width=butw))
            layout.add_widget(Button(background_color=blue2, text='b', size_hint_x=None, width=butw))
            layout.add_widget(Button(background_color=blue, text='c',  size_hint_x=None, width=butw))
    # cont.
            return layout

    MyApp().run()
```

Thanks, Ryan

Answer (score 1):

So, on line 12, `print('The button 1 is being pressed' % instance.text)` you're trying to format a string but you didn't specify where to put the instance's text. Otherwise, this code I edited a little (please remove all the unneeded code from the example next time) works fine, it prints when the "a" button is pressed:

```
import kivy 
kivy.require('1.10.0') 
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout 
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        def callback(instance):
            print('The button 1 is being pressed',  instance.text)

        # test 1: I dont think this works because it doesn't work with the grid structure but I tried it anyways
        btn1 = Button(text='a', size_hint_x=None, width=30)

        btn1.bind(on_press=callback)

        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, rows=28)
        layout.add_widget(btn1)
        layout.add_widget(Button(text='b', size_hint_x=None, width=30))
        layout.add_widget(Button(text='c',  size_hint_x=None, width=30))

        return layout

MyApp().run()
```

[image: App works fine]

Do the same for other buttons with other functions and you're done.